# Dart - Dio - Converting Latin2 text to UTF-8

Tags: flutter, dart, character-encoding, dio

How is it possible converting to UTF-8 from Latin2 by using dio library?

I fetch a website content by using the dio

```
  final response = await dio.get(url, options: Options(
        responseType: ResponseType.plain,
    ));
  final responseData = response.data;
  return response.toString();
```

when I debug the `responseData`, the special latin2 characters are replaced by question marks, however when I open the browser and check it, I see the special encoded chars: VirĂĄg

Unfortunately in dart it is Vir�g.

How can I resolve this charset issue in dart lang?

Comment: You'll likely need https://pub.dev/packages/enough_convert which I presume comes with examples.  Don't use anything that isn't 8859-2 specific, because the character mappings to unicode might not be correct.